# Convert a HEX string to long in C++

Tags: c++, arduino, hex

I'm writing my first BLE system for Ardunio and I'm building it on top of an already working system for controlling RGB strip, and currently, I'm using the HEX numbers to know what I'm setting where.

OK reworking the question,

```cpp
#define BLE_RX 5
#define BLE_TX 4

SoftwareSerial BLE(BLE_RX, BLE_TX);

// set the startup color to white
unsigned long color = 0xFFFFFF;
// hold the last color set so we can off / on without losing prior settings
unsigned long lastColor = 0x000000;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  BLE.begin(9600);

  pinMode(GREEN_LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RED_LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BLUE_LED, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println("hello world");
}


void loop() {
  long r = ((color >> 16) & 0xFF);
  long g = ((color >> 8) & 0xFF);
  long b = (color & 0xFF);
  char data[100];
  analogWrite(RED_LED, r);
  analogWrite(GREEN_LED, g);
  analogWrite(BLUE_LED, b);

  readBLE();
}

long hstol(String recv){
  char c[6];
  recv.toCharArray(c, 6);
  return strtol(c, NULL, 16);
}

void readBLE(){
  if(BLE.available() > 0){
    String data = BLE.readString();
    if(data.length() == 6){
      lastColor = color;
      Serial.println(data);
      Serial.println(hstol(data));
      color = hstol(data);
    }
  }
}
```

When I first run my CPP the LED Strip is white as it should be if via BLE I send `FF0000`(red), my LED's go green, this is my output

[image: Serial output from arduino]

When `FF0000` should Equal 16711680, `00FF00` = 65280 and `0000FF` = 255

Comment: Are you allowed to use the C library? `sscanf` will work well enough.

Comment: @john yeah sscanf is available to me

Comment: @Barkermn01 What is the format of `String recv`?

Comment: In the shown `hstol` function you don't need the temporary `c` array (which is invalid anyway, since C++ doesn't support [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)), use [`c_str`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/c_str/) to get a pointer to pass to [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol). And please read the linked documentation for `strtol`, it tells you exactly what it expects (i.e. no `0x` prefix for base `16`, but you can use it for base `0` to autodetect base).

Comment: So something like `sscanf(str, "%lx", &val);` but `strtoul` will also work and you rejected that above for reasons I don't understand

Comment: If you want you code to work with strings like `0xFF0000`, you need to call `strtol(recv.c_str(), NULL, 0)` i.e. set the base to 0(auto-detect). Your code will work for strings like `FF0000`.

Comment: @brc-dd at the moment just FF0000 this also goes for `some programmer dude`, why is because it did not work and I don't understand how it works. like I said it's not my code it's from the Arduino forums I would normally just throw it though `istringstream` and `std::hex`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude also your correct, but you're forgetting it's not variable at the time of creation it's fixed length plus a value. https://techiedelight.com/compiler/?run=I2NPZs

Comment: The length of the string `recv` is unknown at compile-time. C++ specifies that array-sizes must be known at compile-time (they must be compile-time constants). If you use a value that is known only at run-time then you have a VLA (Variable-Length Array). Unfortunately some compilers allow it as a non-portable extension of the language. Please make it a habit to never use such non-portable extensions.

Comment: @Barkermn01 Can you provide me what you are getting on serial monitor by running this on an Arduino board? https://create.arduino.cc/editor/brc-dd/5087b0e1-fa98-4463-a5b5-3d5011a05f1c/preview (I don't have a board at hand right now, otherwise I had myself confirmed it.)

Comment: Regarding `strtol`, if the contents of `recv` is e.g. `"0xFF0000"` then you can use it as `strtol(recv.c_str()), 0, 0)`, or as `strtol(recv.c_str() + 2, 0, 16)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah I know I could substring it to sort it out because it's actually going to be 8 char hex so it can do other options as well so OPCODE of `0x CMD(2),R(2),G(2),B(2)` but for now I just want it working, I have updated the question to show all the code and what is going wrong.

Comment: @Barkermn01 As per your new question, change array size to be `7` inside `hstol`. It will work fine then. Remember strtol is based on `\0` ended strings.

Comment: It seems the `"0x"` prefix is not part of the string, so then just `strtol(recv.c_str(), 0, 16)`?

Comment: @brc-dd thanks that got it working

Comment: Do anyone of you want to create and answer so I can mark it as correct @brc-dd perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source of error in your posted code: you are using an array of 6 characters while it should be 7 to hold the whole `recv` string. Your code is currently showing an undefined behavior because `strtol` searches for null/whitespace character to finish parsing which is never present within bounds in `char c[6]`.

I would recommend using this type of approach. It is just a single line thing, without requiring extra memory for some temporary character array. (Also saves the time, otherwise wasted in copying the hex string).

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  String x1 = "FF0000";
  long y1 = strtol(x1.c_str(), NULL, 16); // <--
  Serial.print(y1); // prints 16711680
  Serial.println();
  
  String x2 = "0xFF0000";
  long y2 = strtol(x2.c_str(), NULL, 0); // <--
  Serial.print(y2); // prints 16711680
  Serial.println();
  
  long y3 = strtol(x2.c_str() + 2, NULL, 16); // <--
  Serial.print(y3); // prints 16711680
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
    
}
```